# Windows 8.1 font issue. Blocky, Pixelated weird. (Broswer)

Tags: fonts

I have been searching the forums a lot, but couldnt find an appropriate answer to the font rendering issue I am encountering. It has nothing to do with the ClearType settings, because my windows fonts are fine.

The font rendering is in the Browser, but it doesnt matter if its Firefox, Chrome or IE. 
Its not on all websites but on a lot, even on facebook. 
In the image it should be iWatch and it looks like and 'L'. 
On my other computer its fine though.

Can someone shed some light on it.

An image is attached.

[image]